# OpenSSL Windows: error in req

Tags: windows, openssl

I created a new private key using `openssl genrsa -out my-prvkey.pem 1024`
but when I want create the certificate: `req -new -key my-prvkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out my-pubcert.pem`
I get error: `error in req`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
openssl genrsa -out my-prvkey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -key my-prvkey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -config "C:/Program Files <x86>/GnuWin32/share/openssl.cnf" -out my-pubcert.pem
```

I guess the error is generated because of the openssl.cnf file